# WatiN: How to check one radio button out of a radio button group

Tags: collections, radio-button, watin

I've been using [WatiN](http://watin.org/) in C# for about 2 months now for quick checks for online surveys I develop. I've gotten pretty good with it but I'm still having one issue that I can't find an answer to. I know how to iterate through all the radio buttons on the page but I can't seem to find out how to make it only check one radio button in a group.

So far I've used radio collections to find all the radio buttons on the page. Then I'll use a foreach loop to check all the radio buttons. I mean yes, its doing exactly what I told it to do but how do I get it to only check one radio button out of a group instead of checking ever button on the page?

Is there such thing as radio button collections? Any articles, tips, or pointers would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure they are in the same group?

Here is some sample code that works as I would expect it.  Click one radio button and it selects while the others in the group deselect.

```
        ie.GoTo("http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        ie.RadioButton(Find.ByName("group2")).Click();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
        ie.RadioButton(Find.ByName("group2") && Find.ByIndex(1)).Click();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
        ie.RadioButton(Find.ByName("group2") && Find.ByIndex(2)).Click();
```

Sleeps are in there just to give me enough time to scroll down on the page and watch what is happening.

Comment: BTW, the above works as expected using IE8, WatiN 2.0.  Other versions not tested.

Comment: +1 Just what I needed. `&& Find.ByIndex(1)` works a treat with `Find.ById` as well. Cheers.